# Extraxt IP and javascript string from string with pregmatch

Tags: php, regex

i want to be able to extract the IP and some other text but i could not do it !! am very bad in regex :(

here's what i've tried so far :

```
$string='<td>189.3.215.146<script type="text/javascript">document.write(":"+h+g+h+g)</script>';



preg_match_all("|<td>([.]{1,3}\.[.]{1,3}\.[.]{1,3}\.[.]{1,3})</[^>]+>document\.write\(\":\"([^)]+)\)</script>|U",
    $string,
    $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    print_r($out);
```

Its not working for some reason :(

EDIT : 
i want to extract the `+h+g+h+g` from `document.write(":"+h+g+h+g)`

Comment: What other text do you want to extract?

Comment: Hi sorry , forgot to mention the other text : i want to extract the +h+g+h+g from document.write(":"+h+g+h+g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only have that kind of text, here's some example regexes:

```
<?php

$string='<td>189.3.215.146<script type="text/javascript">document.write(":"+h+g+h+g)</script>';

$ips = array();
preg_match_all('/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/', $string, $ips);

$writes = array();
preg_match_all('/document.write\(([^)]+)\)/', $string, $writes);

print_r($ips);
print_r($writes);
```

You can put it all in one regex, but I think it's clearer this way.

EDIT: Just in case you prefer it, here's a way to do it with one regex (more of the same really)

```
<?php

$string = '<td>189.3.215.146<script type="text/javascript">document.write(":"+h+g+h+g)</script>';

$ipRegex    = '(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})';
$writeRegex = 'document.write\(([^)]+)\)';
$matches    = array();
preg_match_all("/$ipRegex.*$writeRegex/", $string, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Comment: :) actually it is a table with entries like the line i am trying to parse , they are all identical except the IP address and the +g+h thing . i am trying to put them all in one regex as the +g+h is linked to the IP (the port numbers)

Comment: @RonanDejhero I have updated my code to extract only the text within `document.write`, should work now. If all IPs have some text, the array indexes will match in the 2 array results. Otherwise you will need to make 1 regex, indeed - let me know if you need only 1 regex or not.

Comment: @RonanDejhero Ok, I have also added an example which uses only one regex.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex :

`|<td>([.]{1,3}\.[.]{1,3}\.[.]{1,3}\.[.]{1,3})</[^>]+>document\.write\(\":\"([^)]+)\)</script>|U`

doesn't match what you want, here is an explanation :

```
<td>                     : match <td>
(                        : start capture group 1
[.]{1,3}\.               : one to three dots followed by a dot
[.]{1,3}\.               : same
[.]{1,3}\.               : same
[.]{1,3}                 : one to three dots
              ### all this can be simplify by: \.{7,15} : 7 to 15 dots !!!
              ### this is not what you want.

)                        : end of capture group 1
<                        : <
/                        : /
[^>]+                    : one or more chars NOT >
>                        : >
document\.write\(\":\"   : document.write(":"
(                        : start capture group 2
[^)]+                    : one or more chars NOT )
)                        : end of capture group 2
\)                       : )
</script>                : </script>
```

I'd do:

```
|<td>(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}).+?document\.write\(\":\"([^)]+)\)</script>|
```

With this one you'll retrieve the IP address in group 1 and +h+g+h+g in group 2

**explanation:**

```
<td>                      : <td>
(                         : start capture group 1
\d{1,3}                   : 1 to 3 digits
(?:                       : start NON capture group
\.\d{1,3}                 : a dot followed by 1 to 3 digits
){3}                      : end NON capture group, must appear 3 times
)                         : end capture group 1
.+?                       : any number of any char NOT greedy
document\.write\(\":\"    : document.write(":"
(                         : start capture group 2
[^)]+                     : one or more chars NOT )
)                         : end capture group 2
\)                        : )
</script>                 : </script>
```